# Ionic 3 Google Maps Plugins

Tags: plugins, native, ionic3

am using Ionic 3-Angular 4 to build an app, and I am trying to add Google Maps native SDK plugin and I keep getting the following Error:

```
Error: Failed to fetch plugin file:node_modules/cordova-plugin-googlemaps via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 4294963229 Error output:
npm ERR! path C:\Users\shawe\Desktop\Xampp Server\Ionic\beitelmagdes\node_modules\cordova-plugin-googlemaps\npm-shrinkwrap.json
npm ERR! code ELOOP
npm ERR! errno -4067
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, open 'C:\Users\shawe\Desktop\Xampp Server\Ionic\beitelmagdes\node_modules\cordova-plugin-googlemaps\npm-shrinkwrap.json'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\shawe\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-11-16T07_43_23_428Z-debug.log

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable
API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID=AIza... (exit code 1).
```

Please Help

Comment: Please give details like what you did (where did you add the dependency?), code samples, ...

Comment: Also, linking the complete log would help

Comment: das_j, I am really still new to this. So, where would you get this log from?

Comment: No worries, we all started there. I have no idea about Ionic3, but providing relevant lines (probably the end) of the complete log mentioned in what you provided would help. Also, how did you add the dependency?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and seemed to be an issue with the repro. It is now working nicely if you follow the ionic-native documentation:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/

```
    $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable 
      API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY_IS_HERE" --variable 
      API_KEY_FOR_IOS="YOUR_IOS_API_KEY_IS_HERE"
    $ npm install --save @ionic-native/google-maps
```